# Is it possible to target a specific page template in sitecore and convert all pages of that template into an SXA pages

Tags: sxa, content-editor, content-management

Recently we have upgraded to `Sitecore 10 XP`, some of our pages are still using old templates. Is it possible to target a specific page template in `Sitecore` and convert all pages of that template into an `SXA pages`?

Comment: What have you tried? You could probably just make your page template inherit from your SXA Tenant's `Page` template.

Comment: Did you upgrade from Sitecore to Sitecore SXA?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template using menu "CONFIGURE" -> Change option. You can select your SXA page template.

[image]

If you have lots of pages and want to convert in one shot. You can write powershell script to have this change.

Hoping this will help you.